# toolstripbutton error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, toolstripbutton

I have a toolstripbutton that contains this code:

```
Dim total, tXS, tS, tM, tL, tXL As Integer

    For i = 0 To dvJOBranch.Rows.Count - 1
        tXS += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("XS").Value
        tS += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("S").Value
        tM += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("M").Value
        tL += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("L").Value
        tXL += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("XL").Value
    Next

    total = tXS + tS + tM + tL + tXL

    MsgBox(total)
```

Its only works once, like for example, if my datagridview cell contains all zeros, the total is zero, and then when I input numbers in  the first row of the columns(for example I input 5), the total is zero again.

But if I put this code in a button, it works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by `total` is a Label .. then you may put your code in your `datagridview_cellvalidated` event ..

```
Dim total as Integer

Private Sub dvJOBranch_CellValidated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dvJOBranch.CellValidated

Dim tXS, tS, tM, tL, tXL As Integer

For i = 0 To dvJOBranch.Rows.Count - 1
    tXS += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("XS").Value
    tS += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("S").Value
    tM += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("M").Value
    tL += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("L").Value
    tXL += dvJOBranch.Rows(i).Cells("XL").Value
Next

total = tXS + tS + tM + tL + tXL

'MsgBox(total)

End Sub
```

In your ToolStripButton put the code `Msgbox(total)`

Comment: Hi sir, the TOTAL is the variable I use, not a label. Can you explain how can I put it in the cell validated, thank you

Comment: Tnx for this sir, I wil try it.

Comment: Hi sir, this is working for me, but every time I put value in the datagridview, its always popping out, I need to pop once. tnx

Comment: I want to pop out when I click the toolstripbutton

Comment: @Matthew .. Sorry I dont get it, if you want to pop up by clicking TSB, you original code has already worked isn't it ? .. you will need this code if you want always count the total after you input in specific column ..

Comment: Hi sir, my code is working but only in the first run, for example the total columns in the first run is 10, it will pop out 10, then if I change some values in the cell and the total is 20, it will pop out 10 again instead of 20.

Comment: @Matthew .. It's updated .. Declare the total in Class form (not in the sub)